# File system turns read only after waking Dell XPS 9370 laptop up from suspend

Tags: linux, filesystems, suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 13 (9370). Recently my main file system has been turning read-only when I wake my laptop up from suspend (i.e. open the lid).

Relevant output from dmesg:

```
[95469.731682] OOM killer enabled.                                                                                
[95469.731684] Restarting tasks ... done.                                                                         
[95469.741792] [drm] RC6 on                                                                                       
[95469.763521] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p3): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4618: inode #3408659: block 13631569: comm Xwayland: unable to read itable block
[95469.763529] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p3, logical block 0, lost sync page write                           
[95469.763531] Aborting journal on device nvme0n1p3-8.                                                            
[95469.763535] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p3, logical block 57180160, lost sync page write                    
[95469.763536] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for nvme0n1p3-8.                          
[95469.763538] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): Remounting filesystem read-only                                               
[95469.763541] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p3) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5761: IO failure                      
[95469.763543] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): previous I/O error to superblock detected                                     
[95469.763544] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p3, logical block 0, lost sync page write                           
[95469.763546] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p3) in ext4_dirty_inode:5945: IO failure                              
[95469.763548] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): previous I/O error to superblock detected                                     
[95469.763549] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p3, logical block 0, lost sync page write                           
[95469.835805] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): ext4_writepages: jbd2_start: 9223372036854775806 pages, ino 25579170; err -30 
[95469.836523] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p3) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5761: Journal has aborted             
[95469.836535] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): previous I/O error to superblock detected                                     
[95469.837801] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p3) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5761: Journal has aborted             
[95469.842400] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p3) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5761: Journal has aborted             
[95469.907749] PM: suspend exit
```

There seem to be some clear red flags there but how do I go about resolving these errors?

Comment: You might want to try a quick self-check with `smartctl -H /dev/nvme0`.  And there might be something in `smartctl -l error /dev/nvme0`.  [smartctl supports NVMe, although the support might still be experimental](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/NVMe_Support).

Comment: Some obvious search terms found 0 bugs in the Ubuntu tracker. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/linux?field.searchtext=suspend+IO+error&search=Search You could try reporting there (make sure to read the guidelines about required information). Especially if you found a kernel version that *doesn't* have the problem.

Comment: You should try seeing if one your older kernel updates avoids the problem (kernel versions in GRUB boot menu).  I think, if it is a kernel regression within 18.04, it is a regression within the Ubuntu 4.15.0-x.y series.  Ubuntu is on its own here; it's not related to any of the official linux-stable branches.